# Spring boot registry to hold data from external API

Tags: spring-boot, registry, spring-cloud-stream

I am building a spring cloud microservice processor that maps data through an external API, I wand to add a registry component that holds the mapped data after mapping instead of calling the API for the same information on each message.

Is there any available registries in Spring, spring boot, spring cloud that I can utilize instead of building one from scratch?

I can not cache the API requestd as I am bounded to memory constrains due to large number of data.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Gemfire/Redis External Caching Mechanism if cannot be cached at Application Level.

Comment: Can not use any external services due to security reasons.

Comment: What i mean is setup caching server within your premises/internal server and use those in the services. We are using gemfire/Redis based on the requirement and those are setup internal to org and using those instances as a service for our micorservices. We are on Pivotal Cloud Foundry.